# DNS and Web Local Servers and NAT

Tags: dns, nat

I'm doing a scenario about DNS and NAT in [Packet Tracer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_Tracer):

[image: DNS and NAT]

As shown in the image, I write a default route and NAT on Router1. I want to request `www.apfz.ir` from the PC1 browser through the Internet or WAN connection. When I do, I get this message:

> Host Unresolved

I have two questions:

1. What DNS I must set for the PC1 DNS section? (I am Internet User).
2. Is my NAT Configuration enough for requesting a web page through DNS Server or I must do something more?

Comment: The job of a NAT router is to keep all internal IP addresses internal. Therefore from outside you will never be able to access a PC with a NAT-internal IP address.

Comment: Unless the routers support hosting and connecting to a VPN, in which case each side will have local access to both subnets when connected via VPN.  https://www.howtogeek.com/221001/how-to-set-up-your-own-home-vpn-server/

Comment: @Robert PC1 wants to reach my webserver through the internet I mean.